# Replacement for TraversalDescription.toJson in neo4j 1.8.1

Tags: java, neo4j

I am currently running through the tutorial here:  [Neo4j 1.8.1 docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.8.1/server-java-rest-client-example.html) and since documentation wasn't kept up to date the tutorial is invalid to say the least.  What I am trying to do is replace the following code:

```
public void foo()
{
   TraversalDescription t = new TraversalDescription();
t.setOrder( TraversalDescription.DEPTH_FIRST );
t.setUniqueness( TraversalDescription.NODE );
t.setMaxDepth( 10 );
t.setReturnFilter( TraversalDescription.ALL );
}
```

With the new way of doing things as `TraversalDescription` has been moved to an interface and had several functions removed such as the `setOrder` function.

Comment: As you figured out yourself, the TraversalDescription used in the example is a custom class that generates the correct JSON needed for the remote call. We'll update the docs.

Comment: @MichaelHunger Indeed I did, ideally I stop getting so confused :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the following syntax:

```
for (Path position : Traversal.description()
    .depthFirst()
    .uniqueness(Uniqueness.NODE_GLOBAL)
    .evaluator(Evaluators.toDepth(10)
    .traverse(yourStartNode)) {
```

}

Comment: FWIW this is only valid with Neo4J nodes not URI as several examples on the neo4j website show.

Answer (score 0):

The TraversalDescription used in neo4j tutorial is not the interface present in neo4j core jars, it is a custom class present in their example code.

You can check out the classes at

http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.neo4j.examples/neo4j-server-examples/1.9.M04/

You will also have to copy the Relationships class.

Perhaps this tutorial can also help you as well 
http://weblog4j.com/2013/07/22/neo4j-a-next-generation-graph-database-and-java/

Regards